# How to fix boot error UUID disk drive is not ready or not present where micro failed to load microcode_amd.bin and HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed?

Tags: linux-mint, boot

When I updated to the new Kernel 3.7.2, everything goes ok, but when it comes to powering on Linux Mint, it shows me two warnings:

[image]
[image]

What's wrong and what can I do?

Comment: I just edited images. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have installed AMD CPU you need to get latest microcode from [AMD site](http://www.amd64.org/index.php?id=50&file=amd-ucode-latest.tar) But it seems site is down right now.

2) For fixing disk UUID error you should check `/etc/fstab/` for absent partitions.

Comment: I solved problem #2. I just deleted line of the code where is swap partition defined.
I can`t open that AMD link that dchirikov sended. Any alternative?

Comment: I just saw at this page [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Microcode#AMD_CPUs) that my processor family is not on the list. My processor family is 16. Any idea how to fix beside that?

Comment: It's [looks like](http://web.archive.org/web/20120624102653/http://www.amd64.org/support/microcode.html) you really have no support for your CPU. I guess you can disable microcode module by executing `blacklist microcode >> /etc/modprobe.d/microcode.conf`

Comment: How is that going to effect on system performance etc.?

Comment: I dont'n know really. You'd better test it.

Comment: Or is it better solution to downgrade to 3.6.11, because on pev. version of kernel I don`t have this problem?

Comment: Check if there is a file called `/lib/firmware/amd-ucode/microcode_amd.bin`. If there isn't, and there is no package containing it, I wouldn't worry.